# SQL Server - find people between date range excluding the year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table EMPLOYEE containing Employee info as mentioned below:

```
ID     NAME     DOB
1      ABC      1974-01-01
2      BDS      1984-12-31
3      QWE      1959-05-27

and so on
```

I want to list all the employees whose DOB is in the given range.

```
select * from EMPLOYEE where DOB BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '1980-02-27'
```

I have a filter condition to **'include year in date comparison'**, which when selected **'NO'**, the employee DOB day and DOB month
only should be considered for comparison. **and not the year.**

**For example:** If I enter the date range as '1970-01-01' and '1980-02-27' and the filter is selected as 'NO' then it should search for only those employees
whose DOB is greater than equal to JAN-01 and less than equal to FEB-27.

When selected **'Yes'**, it is simply date range as mentioned in above query.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
select * from EMPLOYEE where DOB BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '1980-02-27'
AND MONTH(DOB) >= CASE WHEN 'NO'='NO' THEN MONTH('1970-01-01')
ELSE MONTH(DOB) END
AND MONTH(DOB) <= CASE WHEN 'NO'='NO' THEN MONTH('1980-02-27')
ELSE MONTH(DOB) END
AND DAY(DOB) >= CASE WHEN 'NO'='NO' THEN DAY('1970-01-01')
ELSE DAY(DOB) END
AND DAY(DOB) <= CASE WHEN 'NO'='NO' THEN DAY('1980-02-27')
ELSE DAY(DOB) END
```

It works when I pass the date range where the FROM date has smaller number month than the TO date month.

For example:
It doesnt work when I pass the date range as '1970-12-01' to '1980-01-31'.
It should list the employees whose DOB is in DEC and JAN month.

Need help please.

Comment: looking at the spec for your search, then if you leave out the year comparison then your query should return no results.  Since without the year comparison, no one has a birthday after 1st december and before 31st Jan

Comment: @JamieA - what do you mean? Anyone born on any day of December or January satisfies the criterion.

Comment: If I replace the dates in your 4th sentence with your test dates then it reads" If I enter the date range as '1970-12-01' and '1980-01-31' and the filter is selected as 'NO' then it should search for only those employees whose DOB is greater than equal to Dec-01 and less than equal to JAN-31".  which is no one.

Comment: ID 2 has a DOB of Dec-31 and ID 1 has a DOB of Jan-01

Comment: @RichBenner ID2 does not satisfy 'less than equal to JAN-31'.  ID 1 does not satisfy 'Greater than equal to Dec-01' . I think I can see what the OP is trying to achieve, but the spec in the question will exclude both of those records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Data;

```
DECLARE @Date_From date; SET @Date_From = '1970-12-01'
DECLARE @Date_To date; SET @Date_To = '1974-01-31'
DECLARE @IncludeYear bit; SET @IncludeYear = 0

CREATE TABLE #Employee (ID int, Name varchar(10), DOB date)
INSERT INTO #Employee (ID, Name, DOB)
VALUES
(1,'ABC','1974-01-01')
,(2,'BDS','1984-12-31')
,(3,'QWE','1959-05-27')
```

This is the query I've made. Tried to cover for every eventuality.

```
SELECT
e.ID
,e.Name
,e.DOB
FROM #Employee e
WHERE
    (
    @IncludeYear = 1
    AND
    DOB BETWEEN @Date_From AND @Date_To
    )
OR
(
@IncludeYear = 0
AND
(
    (
    DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_From) = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_To)
    AND 
    DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB) = DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_To)
    )
OR
    (
    DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_From) < DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_To)
    AND
    DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB) BETWEEN DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_From) AND DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_To)
    )
OR
    (
    DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_From) > DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_To)
    AND
        (
        DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB) > DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_From)
        OR
        DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB) < DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, @Date_To)
        )
    )
)
)
```

- First part of the where clause checks if the @date_from and @date_to
  are the same date, then only returns these.
- Second part checks if the day of year for @date_from comes before
  @date_to. If it does then return everything between these days of the
  year.
- Final part checks if the day of year for @date_to comes before
  @date_from then it gets everything with the day of year after
  @date_from or before @date_to

The results for this one come out as this;

```
ID  Name    DOB
1   ABC     1974-01-01
2   BDS     1984-12-31
```

Comment: I've tried every solution given here. But this one worked perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @includeYear bit = 0, -- if 0 - we don't include year, 1 - include 
        @dateFrom date ='1970-12-01',
        @dateTo date ='1980-05-30'

IF @includeYear = 1 
BEGIN
    SELECT e.*
    FROM EMPLOYEE e
    INNER JOIN (SELECT @dateFrom as dF, @dateTo as dT) d
        ON e.DOB BETWEEN dF AND dT
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT e.*
    FROM EMPLOYEE e
    INNER JOIN (SELECT @dateFrom as dF, @dateTo as dT) d
        ON e.DOB BETWEEN 
        (CASE WHEN MONTH(dF) > MONTH(dT) 
                THEN  DATEADD(year,YEAR(e.DOB)-YEAR(d.dF)-1,dF)
                ELSE  DATEADD(year,YEAR(e.DOB)-YEAR(d.dF),dF) END)
                AND DATEADD(year,YEAR(e.DOB)-YEAR(d.dT),dT)
        OR e.DOB BETWEEN DATEADD(year,YEAR(e.DOB)-YEAR(d.dF),dF) AND
        (CASE WHEN MONTH(dF) > MONTH(dT) 
                THEN  DATEADD(year,YEAR(e.DOB)-YEAR(d.dT)+1,dT)
                ELSE  DATEADD(year,YEAR(e.DOB)-YEAR(d.dT),dT) END)
END
```

For

```
dateFrom    dateTo
1970-12-01  1980-01-30
```

Output:

```
ID  NAME    DOB
1   ABC     1974-01-01
2   BDS     1984-12-31
```

For

```
dateFrom    dateTo
1970-05-01  1980-06-30
```

Output:

```
ID  NAME    DOB
3   QWE     1959-05-27
```

For

```
dateFrom    dateTo
1970-05-01  1980-05-30
```

Output:

```
ID  NAME    DOB
3   QWE     1959-05-27
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Try the function `DATEPART(dayofyear, date)`
In case the day-of-year of the first date is smaller than the day-of-year of the second date, then the day-of-year of the DOB should be between the specified days-of-year.
Otherwise, the day-of-year of the DOB should be either smaller than the day-of-year of the second date or greater than the day-of-year of the first date.

I hope I expressed myself well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than working case-by-case and disassembling and reassembling parts of dates, I've tried to make life easier:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null, Name varchar(17) not null, DOB date not null)
insert into @t(ID,NAME,DOB) values
(1,'ABC','19740101'),
(2,'BDS','19841231'),
(3,'QWE','19590527')

declare @Start date
declare @End date
declare @IncludeYear bit

select @Start='19701201',@End='19800131',@IncludeYear=0

;With Normalized as (
    select
        ID,
        Name,
        CASE WHEN @IncludeYear=1 THEN DOB
            ELSE DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,DOB,'20000101'),DOB)
        END as DOB,
        CASE WHEN @IncludeYear=1 THEN @Start
            ELSE DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,@Start,'20000101'),@Start)
        END as StartRange,
        CASE WHEN @IncludeYear=1 THEN @End
            ELSE DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,@End,'20000101'),@End)
        END as EndRange
    from
        @t
)
select * from Normalized
where
    DOB between StartRange and EndRange or
    (
        @IncludeYear=0 and StartRange>EndRange and
        (
            DOB < EndRange or DOB > StartRange
        )
    )
```

We create the `Normalized` CTE that, does nothing if `@IncludeYear` is 1 or, if it is zero, it resets all dates so that they occur in 2000 (arbitrarily selected).

We then do the straightforward query based on the CTE. The one circumstance where it won't correctly match is when you have your range defined over a year-end transition and we don't care about years - which we can check specifically for and cater for within the end of the `WHERE` clause.

Results:

```
ID          Name              DOB        StartRange EndRange
----------- ----------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           ABC               2000-01-01 2000-12-01 2000-01-31
2           BDS               2000-12-31 2000-12-01 2000-01-31
```

Results with `@Start='19700101',@End='19800227',@IncludeYear=1`:

```
ID          Name              DOB        StartRange EndRange
----------- ----------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           ABC               1974-01-01 1970-01-01 1980-02-27
```

Comment: As much as I like your simplicity (and use of SARGs), is it necessary to run the query on the entire table row by row?

Comment: Sure enough, as when I tested the results on [AdventureWorks2012].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail], your query cost 2x as much with just 19k rows.

Did not know it would be that steep, but it makes sense since your changing every single row.

Comment: @clifton_h - **if** this is a common query and **if** its performance isn't acceptable, the first thing I would look to do would be to implement a persisted computed column containing the normalized DOB and index that. The general strategy of this answer would tend to stay the same.

Comment: Actually, I was more interested in the theory. Your code by far was simplest to read, still used a SARG, and I was curious on my end what the impact might be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
declare @flag varchar(3) ='NO';
declare @sd date ='1980-02-27';
declare @ed date ='1970-01-01';

select tt.*
from (select sd = month(@sd)*100 + day(@sd),
      ed = month(@ed)*100 + day(@ed)
     ) prm      
cross join
    -- test data, place real table here
    ( 
        values 
        (1,'ABC', cast('1974-01-05' as date)),
        (2,'BDS','1984-12-31'),
        (3,'QWE','1959-05-27')
    ) tt(ID,NAME, DOB)
cross apply (select md = month(DOB)*100 + day(DOB)) tx  
where @flag ='YES' and DOB between @sd and @ed
    or @flag ='NO' and (prm.sd<=prm.ed and tx.md  between prm.sd and prm.ed
                        or prm.sd>prm.ed and (tx.md <= prm.ed or tx.md >= prm.sd));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
DECLARE @employee table(EmployeeID varchar(10), DOB date);

INSERT INTO @employee(EmployeeID, DOB)
    VALUES('0001', '01-Dec-1990'),
        ('0002', '06-Jan-1993'),
        ('0003', '04-Mar-1987'),
        ('0004', '12-Feb-1996');


DECLARE @dateStart date = '01-Jan-1990';
DECLARE @dateEnd date = '27-Feb-1997';
DECLARE @includeYear bit = 0;

If @includeYear = 0
Begin
    SET @dateStart = CAST(('2000-' + CAST(MONTH(@dateStart) AS varchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(DAY(@dateStart) as varchar(10))) AS date);
    SET @dateEnd = CAST(('2000-' + CAST(MONTH(@dateEnd) AS varchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(DAY(@dateEnd) as varchar(10))) AS date);
End

If @includeYear = 1
Begin
    SELECT  *
    FROM    @employee
    WHERE   DOB BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd
End
Else
Begin
    SELECT  *
    FROM    @employee
    WHERE   CAST(('2000-' + CAST(MONTH(DOB) AS varchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(DAY(DOB) as varchar(10))) AS date) BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd
End
```

As you can see we are just making the year part of the query a constant if you don't want to include year. This query seems to be a bit slower but if you add another computed column in your table, where you save the date with a constant year then you just need to put where criteria on that particular column.

Answer (score 0):

- Always use a SARG in your predicate. Any answer that fails to do this only results in lost performance and your DBA getting upset.

What you want is two different queries to run depending on the answer to the Procedure. Since this is a proc that likely runs a lot, store the answers into a variable in your PROC and run any adjusting code from there. Not only will this make your code more robust by flushing out errors beforehand, but SQL Server has a better chance of guessing the variables to use with your indexes.

The following PROC will work. Feel free to use part or all of it:

```
CREATE TABLE #table_E (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(3), DOB DATE)
INSERT INTO #table_E (ID , Name, DOB)
VALUES (1, 'ABC', '1997-01-02' )
     , (2, 'BDS', '1984-12-31' )
     , (3, 'QWE', '1993-03-22' )

GO

CREATE PROC USP_EmpCompare (@Date_1 DATE, @Date_2 DATE, @Compare_Year VARCHAR(3))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MONTH_1 INT
          , @Month_2 INT
          , @Day_1   INT
          , @Day_2   INT
          , @Date1  DATE
          , @Date2  DATE
    SET @Date1  = CASE WHEN @Date_1 > @Date_2 THEN @Date_2 ELSE @Date_1 END
    SET @Date2  = CASE WHEN @Date_1 > @Date_2 THEN @Date_1 ELSE @Date_2 END
    SET @Month_1 = CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM, @Date2) > DATEPART(MM, @Date1) THEN DATEPART(MM, @Date1) ELSE DATEPART(MM, @Date2) END
    SET @Month_2 = CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM, @Date1) > DATEPART(MM, @Date2) THEN DATEPART(MM, @Date1) ELSE DATEPART(MM, @Date2) END
    SET @Day_1   = CASE WHEN DATEPART(DD, @Date2) > DATEPART(DD, @Date1) THEN DATEPART(DD, @Date1) ELSE DATEPART(DD, @Date2) END
    SET @Day_2   = CASE WHEN DATEPART(DD, @Date1) > DATEPART(DD, @Date2) THEN DATEPART(DD, @Date1) ELSE DATEPART(DD, @Date2) END
    -- SELECT @Date1, @Date2
    IF @Compare_Year = 'no'
    BEGIN
    ;WITH C AS (SELECT ID
                    , Name
                    , DATEPART(DD, DOB) AS Day
                    , DATEPART(MM, DOB) AS Month
    FROM #table_E)
    SELECT  ID, Name, @Date1, @Date2
    FROM    C
    WHERE   C.Month >= @MONTH_1
        AND C.Month <= @Month_2
        AND C.Day   >= @Day_1
        AND C.DAy   <= @Day_2       
    END
    IF @Compare_Year = 'yes'
    BEGIN

        SELECT ID, Name, DOB
        FROM #table_E
        WHERE DOB <= @Date2
          AND DOB >= @Date1
    END
    ELSE 
        PRINT WHAT! FOLLOW THE RULES YOU FOOL!!!

END
```

jk. that last part about fools is probably not included in your final draft. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would make it very simple not so much complex.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DOB >= '1970-01-01' AND DOB <= '1980-02-27'
```

This filters all dates between these two dates